# IAM roles increase more than maximum quota limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment, aws-cdk

We have more than 300 micro services and we create separate CI/CD Pipelines for all of the services. We are getting an error where IAM roles increase more than the maximum quota limit. Our bucket created a lot.

How can we solve this?

Comment: "IAM roles increase more than max increase quota limit" - hello, could you add details of exact error text, please

Comment: Hello, I made some edits to the question, please see if they are correct

Comment: I have to make cdk infrastructure with pipeline of every micro-service in same micro-service repositories is that good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

Please see if the maximum quota limit for IAM roles i.e. 5000 has not exceeded else please specify the error properly, meanwhile go through the below link for better understanding :
[IAM and AWS quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html)

Comment: Yeah I know there was hard limit of 5000 so we have to divide on AWS Organisation or is there any other solution because cdk Pipeline while creating create more than 11 roles per stack.